# Interpretation of green function, Brownian motion and random times

Tags: brownian-motion, greens-function

I am reading an article on Nevanlinna theory trough brownian motion and they say that
$$g_r(0,z)\,\text dA(z) =\frac 12 \mathbb E[\text{time }Z_s\text{ spends in }\text dA(z)\text{ before exiting }D_r]$$
where $Z_s$ is a complex Brownian motion and $D_r = B_r(0)$ and $g_r(0,z) = \frac1{2\pi}\log \frac{r}{|z|}$ is the Green function satisfying that $g_r(a,b)$ is the potential at $a$ given a unit charge at $b$ inside the grounded shell $\partial D_r$.

I don't understand (maybe intuitively) the relation between such potential $g_r(z,0)$ and the time spent at $\text dA(z)$. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't know if you have already read about the probabilistic representations of solutions to PDEs, maybe it will help you. *An introduction to stochastic integrals* by Evans has some examples such as this one: the solution to $-\frac{1}{2} \Delta u =1$ in $U$ and $u = 0$ in $\partial U$ is given by $u(x) = \mathbb{E} (\tau _x)$ where $\tau_x$ is the first time a Brownian motion starting at $x$ hits $\partial U$.